Live re-load via USB?
I'm using this tutorial to perform live reload of my ionic project changes. My Android phone is connected via USB and I successfully running project generated by ionic. However, when I want to update the project using
ionic cap run android -l --external

it first asks me about target device, which is connected via USB (I am selecting correct one) and then I am getting an error
> capacitor run android --no-sync --target 6ac9be16
[capacitor] ✖ Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
[capacitor]         Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

What I have tried is to set JAVA_HOME and it didn't help
% echo $JAVA_HOME
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home

So my question is if it's possible to live reload the code to the phone connected via USB and how to fix the error?

Try these steps: 1 ) ionic cap sync 2). ionic cap build android (it will open android studio, let it sync project) 3). Close android studio and run ionic cap build android -l --external

This is not live re-load.

I accidentally solved the issue. In the Android Studio Gradle JDK I've added OpenJDK 22.0.2 and it started to work. By default it has only 17.0.11. Now Live re-load works like charm. I am just modifying source file and seeing result on the phone via Wifi (yes, even USB is not connected).
